# How to target specific paragraphs within an HTML string in PHP

Tags: php

A simple one for all your PHP guys out there.
I have a string which represents a portion of HTML. It looks something like this:

```
<p>blablabla.....</p>
<p>blablabla.....</p>
<p>blablabla.....</p>
<p>blablabla.....</p>
<h3>hello</h3>
<p>blablabla.....</p>
<p>blablabla.....</p> etc etc
```

What I would like to do is loop over the nodes applying a class to each, until I hit the h3.

Thanks,

EDIT
I have so far tried:

```
$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
$dochtml->loadHTML($strhtml); 

foreach ($dochtml->childNodes as $node)
{

    if($node->tagName == "p") {
    $node->setAttribute('class', 'someclass');
    } else {
    break;
}
}
```

Which simply doesn't work.

The HTML fragment is from a database and represents the editable portion of a page within a CMS.

Comment: How are you pulling in that HTML fragment?  Not sure PHP is the best approach for this sort of thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well:

```
<?php

$string = explode( '<h3>', $string );
$string[0] = str_replace( '<p>', '<p class="foo">', $string[0] );
$string = implode( '<h3>', $string );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$html = '<xml><p>blablabla.....</p>
         <p>blablabla.....</p>
         <p>blablabla.....</p>
         <p>blablabla.....</p>
         <h3>hello</h3>
         <p>blablabla.....</p>
         <p>blablabla.....</p></xml>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($html);

foreach ($xml as $key => $value) {
    if ( $key == 'h3' ) {
        var_dump($value);
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that I have added `<xml>` tag because there should be some root element that contains other items.